# Integrating unity and android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing an `android-app` that is supposed to open a `Unity` scene on a button click in android.

Let me explain it further:
I have developed a 4 scenes `Unity` project. Each scene has a model to be shown in `AR`. I have performed all the work I need to. I exported this project to `android-studio`. Integrated unity project with my android app. Now on different button clicks in android, I want to open different scenes in unity. I am not getting how to do it. I have 4 scenes, but when the unity opens, it opens scene 1.How can I open other scenes? I have written C# script to open different scenes but I don't understand where to attach it.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Are you asking how to swap scenes? how to tell if a button is pressed? what have you done, what failed?

Comment: Hi Makhtoom, welcome to Stack Overflow! It's unclear what you're actually asking. Take a look at the guidelines on how to ask a good question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons should call:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html
to load a scene.
This does not work in the editor, only in the build itself.
To get it to work you also need to add all the scenes to the build.
You do that by opening a scene, then go to "File->Build Settings->Add open Scenes". Then you should see the scene and scene index in "Scenes in Build"